# Check java version in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to check the java version in my makefile and then exit out if the version is not correct.

```
checkJava::
      ifeq ($(shell java -version | grep "1.5.0"),0)
           @echo "Found version"
      else
           $(error "Could not find correct java version, please install 1.5")
      endif
```

When doing this the java -version output is not going where I am expecting and it is not working. Suggestions of how to fix it? Thank you!

Edit:
added closing quote after grep

Comment: You're missing a end quote in the grep part of your shell statement.

Comment: Whoops didn't copy it in quite right. Any idea now that I fixed that? it doesn't solve the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print the status code, because the output is returned. You also need to make sure the java -version goes to stdout -- my IBM JDK sent it to stderr.

```
ifeq ($(shell java -version 2>&1|grep 1.5.0 >/dev/null; printf $$?),0)
```

Comment: Awesome that works! Thank you so much. And one more question, what here is doing what with the 2>&1, >/dev/null;, printf $$?

Is the 2>&1 sending it to standard out, and the printf printing/returning the 0/1 that grep returns?

Comment: Yes, that is what each piece does